# compiling a C++ class in Xcode: error during compilation: stl vector

Tags: c++, xcode, porting

I have a C++ class that compiles fine on linux with gcc and on widows in visual studio.

boid.h:

```
#ifndef BOID_CLASS_HEADER_DEFINES_H
#define BOID_CLASS_HEADER_DEFINES_H
#include "defines.h"

class Boid {

public:
     // Initialize the boid with random position, heading direction and color
     Boid(float SceneRadius,float NormalVel);

     .....
protected:
     ...
};

#endif
```

and in boid.cpp:

```
#include "Boid.h"

// Initialize the boid with random position, heading direction and color
Boid::Boid(float SceneRadius,float NormalVel) 
{
    ....
}
```

However, I get the following error when I compile this code in Xcode:

```
Compiling Boid.h: "error: vector: No such file or directory"
```

Any ideas? I thought you could take C/C++ code and compile it in Xcode without issues?

Thanks

**EDIT**: Added defines.h (also added #endif to sample, but that was in the original code)

**EDIT 2**: I am getting a different error after a commenting out a couple of includes there were empty: the vector error above.

```
#ifndef BOID_NAV_DEFINES_H
#define BOID_NAV_DEFINES_H
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Vector3d.h"
#include "Point3d.h"
#include "win_layer.h"
#endif
```

Comment: win_layer is commented out, I was missing some functions but it's empty now, I'm going to exclude it from the project

Comment: Now i'm getting an error with vector: "error: vector: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you including the C++ header in a .m file?

.m files are treated as .c files with Objective-C extensions.

.mm files are treated as .cpp files with Objective-C extensions, then it's called Objective-C++

Just rename any .m file to .mm, right-click or ctrl-click and select rename on the file in Xcode.

Comment: I couldn't see the rename option in Xcode so I copied the file in Finder, renamed it to .mm, deleted the .m file from the project in Xcode, and finally added the .mm file to the project in Xcode

Comment: Think nowadays one can select the file in Xcode and select it again a second later and then its name will be editable.

Answer (score 18):

Without changing any .m to .mm or anything like that, if you click your project, click tagets->build settings
go all the way down to **"LLVM GCC 4.2 - Languages"** (new xcode says **"Apple LLVM compiler 4.2"**) you will see **Compile Sources As** change that value to **Objective-C++**;

Answer (score 4):

I hope this will help.
After updating xCode to version 10, I have had issues including < map > and < vector > libraries. Found an easy solution by changing the C++ library type in the project's build settings (target's Build Settings):

**C++ Standard Library: libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++ 11 support)**

Compiled without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're compiling it as C++. Right click the file in XCode and select **Get Info** and make sure that **File Type** is set to **sourcecode.cpp.cpp** for the implementation files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the OS X XCode, that uses gcc to do the actual compiling.  So there should be no difference between that and Linux, other than maybe different versions of gcc.

First thing that jumps out at me here is that you've typed "boid.h" as the name of the file, but you're including "Boid.h".  Assuming that's not a typo, I would expect that to cause trouble on both Linux and OS X....

Edited to answer the new question: Hmmm... vector is definitely part of Xcode: `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.0.0/vector` on my machine.

Further thought: If you port the source and makefiles from the Linux build over to the Mac, you can probably just compile it from the command line exactly like you do on Linux....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you forgot to paste, but you have an unterminated #ifndef

What's inside *defines.h* ?

**Edit:** You seem to have found the solution. One more remark:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

For C++, please:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

:D

Comment: added defines.h to the question, also, #endif is in the original code

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, something in defines.h is affecting the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

This issue had two errors:

- one of my includes had a typo which caused a compile error
- the vector not found error was fixed by the .m files to .mm

Comment: Hi, I accepted the correct answer (after your comment). sorry for the delay