# compiling a #include <cstdlib> in Xcode - error during compilation: file not found

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I have added one framework in my project, where to get the callbacks of framework I need to implement c++ code,for which I have added c++ classes which are .mm from .cpp

[as per suggestions given in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534861/compiling-a-c-class-in-xcode-error-during-compilation-stl-vector)

I also came across few posts of StackOverflow, where I found either I have to go for C++ or Objective C source type(as suggestion of few members).

I am looking to compile c++ code along with Objective C classes,but I am getting file not found error (compile time) for `#include <cstdlib> and #include <string>`

Please let me know any one worked around it.or faced same Issue.

Thanks In Advance!!!

Comment: What's the extension of the source files you're trying to compile?

Comment: Thanks JBL for reply Extension is ".h", file which is type of C Header.

Comment: That's the header, what's the _source_ extension? `.m` or `.mm`?

Comment: .mm(source file) as I mentioned in question.

Answer (score 5):

I think problem is that your's .h-file, where you have added C++ includes is included in other .m-files, not just in .mm.
There is several ways to solve this problem:

1. Use C++ includes only in .mm files. (don't use them in .h)
2. Change **all files**, that import yours header to .mm
3. Include them in

   ```
   #ifdef __cplusplus
   #endif
   ```

block. Also use this block for methods where C++ classes mentioned.
For example:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#endif

@interface SomeClass

#ifdef __cplusplus
- (void) setName:(const string&) name;
#endif

@end
```

Also there is way to avoid `#ifdef #endif` block by using extensions and categories:

1. declare C++'s instance variables only in extensions.
2. create categories with additional .h-file for methods and properties, that use C++'s types.

Comment: If the Objective-C class is declared as using `std::string` then the only option is 1. or 2.  All other options will fail in some way.

Comment: @trojanfoe, do you mean using `std::string` as instance variable?

Comment: Or parameter.  The Objective-C class is only of use to other Objective-C++ classes if it uses C++ classes, so using the `__cplusplus` guard will be of little use anyway.  +1 as you are on the right track.

Comment: @trojanfoe, option 3 is also works. Because you will assess such properties and methods only in .mm-files. I have tested it in objective-c++ job experience.

Comment: Yes it might work, but is somewhat over complicated.  I generally make everything `.mm` if C++ is used in any way at all, as it simplifies things.