# 'cstdlib' file not found when building

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

I started to get **'cstdlib' file not found** error when trying to build very old project.

I was trying to set different paths in the header/library search path, but it did not work.

How should I correctly import cstdlib into my projet?

[image: 'cstdlib' file not found]

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842072/compiling-a-include-cstdlib-in-xcode-error-during-compilation-file-not-fou>

Comment: @Frodyne It is some kind of same question, but answered not in very good way.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling some time I found answer here: http://dev.doukasd.com/2012/03/cstdlib-file-not-found-how-to-fixsolve/

> All you need to do is make sure all files calling C++ methods are treated as C++ files by the compiler – in other words change the extension from .m to .mm (for objective-c++).

Answer (score 0):

You may have chosen the GNU C++ standard library as the CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY in your build settings.

If you use libc++ (LLVM C++ etc).. that problem should vanish.