# How to use Boost with Cocoapods on IOS?

Tags: ios, boost, cocoapods

Has anyone succeeded in using Cocoapods with the Boost pod ?

I do not understand it does not seem to install fully. After pod Install into a blank project I get the below. Is there a step I am missing ?

[image]

This is the output from my install

**pod install --verbose**

```
Analyzing dependencies

Updating spec repositories
  $ /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git rev-parse  >/dev/null 2>&1
  $ /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git rev-parse  >/dev/null 2>&1
Updating spec repo `master`
  $ /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git pull --ff-only
  Already up-to-date.

CocoaPods 0.36.3 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods`

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.


Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods`: (``)
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-PodBoost`: (``)

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
Starting resolution (2015-04-01 15:48:56 +0300)
Creating possibility state for boost (~> 1.57) (1 remaining)
  Attempting to activate boost (1.57.0)
  Activated boost at boost (1.57.0)
  Requiring nested dependencies (boost/string_algorithms-includes (= 1.57.0), boost/shared_ptr-includes (= 1.57.0), boost/pointer_cast-includes (= 1.57.0), boost/numeric-includes (= 1.57.0), boost/preprocessor-includes (= 1.57.0), boost/math-includes (= 1.57.0), boost/graph-includes (= 1.57.0))
  Creating possibility state for boost/string_algorithms-includes (= 1.57.0) (1 remaining)
    Attempting to activate boost/string_algorithms-includes (1.57.0)
    Activated boost/string_algorithms-includes at boost/string_algorithms-includes (1.57.0)
    Requiring nested dependencies ()
    Creating possibility state for boost/shared_ptr-includes (= 1.57.0) (1 remaining)
      Attempting to activate boost/shared_ptr-includes (1.57.0)
      Activated boost/shared_ptr-includes at boost/shared_ptr-includes (1.57.0)
      Requiring nested dependencies ()
      Creating possibility state for boost/pointer_cast-includes (= 1.57.0) (1 remaining)
        Attempting to activate boost/pointer_cast-includes (1.57.0)
        Activated boost/pointer_cast-includes at boost/pointer_cast-includes (1.57.0)
        Requiring nested dependencies ()
        Creating possibility state for boost/numeric-includes (= 1.57.0) (1 remaining)
          Attempting to activate boost/numeric-includes (1.57.0)
          Activated boost/numeric-includes at boost/numeric-includes (1.57.0)
          Requiring nested dependencies ()
          Creating possibility state for boost/preprocessor-includes (= 1.57.0) (1 remaining)
            Attempting to activate boost/preprocessor-includes (1.57.0)
            Activated boost/preprocessor-includes at boost/preprocessor-includes (1.57.0)
            Requiring nested dependencies ()
            Creating possibility state for boost/math-includes (= 1.57.0) (1 remaining)
              Attempting to activate boost/math-includes (1.57.0)
              Activated boost/math-includes at boost/math-includes (1.57.0)
              Requiring nested dependencies ()
              Creating possibility state for boost/graph-includes (= 1.57.0) (1 remaining)
                Attempting to activate boost/graph-includes (1.57.0)
                Activated boost/graph-includes at boost/graph-includes (1.57.0)
                Requiring nested dependencies ()
Finished resolution (8 steps) (Took 0.007472 seconds) (2015-04-01 15:48:56 +0300)
Unactivated: 
Activated: boost, boost/string_algorithms-includes, boost/shared_ptr-includes, boost/pointer_cast-includes, boost/numeric-includes, boost/preprocessor-includes, boost/math-includes, boost/graph-includes

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  A boost

Downloading dependencies

-> Installing boost (1.57.0)
 > Http download
   $ /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /Users/ryanheitner/Projects/PodBoost/Pods/boost/file.tgz "http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.57.0/boost_1_57_0.tar.gz" --create-dirs
     % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   353    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0   423    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0   337    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
100 70.0M  100 70.0M    0     0  2744k      0  0:00:26  0:00:26 --:--:-- 3007k
   $ /usr/bin/tar xfz /Users/ryanheitner/Projects/PodBoost/Pods/boost/file.tgz -C /Users/ryanheitner/Projects/PodBoost/Pods/boost
  - Running pre install hooks

Generating Pods project
  - Creating Pods project
  - Adding source files to Pods project
  - Adding frameworks to Pods project
  - Adding libraries to Pods project
  - Adding resources to Pods project
  - Linking headers
  - Installing targets
    - Installing target `Pods-PodBoost` iOS 8.2
  - Running post install hooks
  - Writing Xcode project file to `Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`
  - Writing Lockfile in `Podfile.lock`
  - Writing Manifest in `Pods/Manifest.lock`
```

Comment: Assuming you did not interrupt the pretty lengthy installation process due to a rather large set of files, your answer is below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why is the Pod not listed?

This is an artifact of `boost` not being an Xcode project, merely a set of files. In addition, you will find that the `boost` inner directory is located properly inside `${PODS_ROOT}/boost`, referenced in **Header Search Path** of *Build Settings*. This is what you gain by using the Pod.

## Pod & Boost hierarchy

The nesting of `boost` in `../Pods/boost/boost` is required to allow the files in the library to refer to themselves as in:

```
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_config.hpp"
```

If you let the operation complete: (the `boost` library is well over 100 MB when zipped)

```
Downloading dependencies
Installing boost (1.57.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

...the while you do not see it in your project, you will find it is in the source tree:

[image]

You can reference it:

```
#import "boost/date_time.hpp"
```

and start dealing with other pressing issues, like locating `#include <cstdlib>`, which is another topic entirely.

## Objective-C++ Compilation

In order to compile `boost`, which is a **C++** library, you need to explicitly refer to it from **C++** source files (not **C** sources, which are the default in `.m`), or adopt alternative solutions listed in [compiling a C++ class in Xcode: error during compilation: stl vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534861/compiling-a-c-class-in-xcode-error-during-compilation-stl-vector).

From a `.mm` file, include these two test lines:

```
#include <cstdlib> // Proof of concept
#import "boost/date_time.hpp"
```

For the sake of this example, I have renamed `main.m` into `main.mm`.
Since the `Pod` did not import any of the `.ipp` files, you could add `NO_BOOST_DATE_TIME_INLINE=1` in **Preprocessor Macros** in *Build Settings*. Doing so, you will get about a dozen of warnings, like the one below, and a successful compilation, without manual import.

> Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'hour_type' (aka 'int')

---

Edit: *deleted an off-topic manual import, not required*

---

Comment: I followed your instruction and then when I add #import "boost/date_time.hpp" to my MyObject.mm file it fails in gregorian_calendar.hpp with #include "boost/date_time/gregorian_calendar.ipp" file not found

Comment: Let me understand this. You need to delete (remove reference) to boost and then to re-add it back to project as a non Pod ? It seems that using a boost.framework is the way to go and Cocoapods is not suitable for such a large library.

Comment: I really don't know whether to accept your answer or not. I appreciate the effort you have put into it but am unsure whether there is a more satisfying answer.

Comment: Hi Ryan. Removed all comments, some confusing. Removed an entire section to bypass Pods (off-topic). Added `.mm` example (**C++** requirement, which may have been where you were stuck) and some **Preprocessor Macros**. The example above compiles, links, builds and runs. Ignoring the 14 compilation warnings, it responds to the question "How to use Boost with Cocoapods on IOS?".

Comment: OK I will accept this, but the pod does seem to be more trouble than it is worth. It did not include all that is need for example <boost/core/typeinfo.hpp> was missing. My feeling is that this pod is best avoided for now.

Comment: Sorry it did not work for you ; at the very least, you got the answer to your question. One note: you could update the Podspec so that it includes `<boost/core/typeinfo.hpp>` and other missing files, and push it to `git` and `cocoapods`. Others will benefit from your participation to this open source endeavor.